# IntelliJ Heap Space limit

Tags: python-3.x, intellij-idea, imagej

I am currently working on a project to perform some basic image analysis using the ImageJ add on for Python and I am using IntelliJ as the IDE. Unfortunately, the images we are trying to analyze cause the following error to occur in IntelliJ: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

I am able to run smaller images through the code, but it would seem that some are too large for IntelliJ to handle and I believe that I have maxed out the heap size at 2048 MB. Is there a way to work around this, or do I need to find a different IDE to work in?

Answer (score 0):

The [IntelliJ docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/increasing-memory-heap-of-the-build-process.html) say:

> To prevent the build process from running out of memory, you can increase the amount of memory allocated to the process. By default, the memory heap is 128 MB, but for large projects you may need more.

> Open the Build File Properties dialog.

> In the Maximum heap size field, type the required amount of memory.

> The memory heap of the build process is independent of the IntelliJ IDEA memory heap, and is released after the build process is complete. For information about the memory heap allocated by the JVM for running IntelliJ IDEA, see Increase the memory heap of the IDE.